# Symfony 1.4 Doctrine: How to call a function in the template page?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

How do we call a php function in the template page in symfony 1.4 doctrine. Suppose i want to call a function add() in the template page where should i define the function add()? Will i do it in the actions page? Can we define tht function in actions page?

Waiting fr a quick reply

Comment: Why do you need the function in the template? Why don't you run the function in the action and just pass the result to the template as a variable

Comment: I need a particular task to be done 5-6 times in the template page. As it is in loop. I m building a timetable module and the classes is needed to be arranged in a grid. So the timetable() function is needed to be called for each row separately

Comment: Try to avoid 'waiting for a quick reply', 'please answer asap'; everyone wants a quick answer, and it's best not to appear impatient :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use helper. For example:

**apps/yourapp/lib/helper/myNewHelper.php**

```
<?php

 if (!function_exists("yourfunc"))
    {

     function yourfunc($variable){

         // Your code here

                                }
        return $variable;
                               }
    }
?>
```

And in themplate, for example

**apps/yourapp/modules/yourmodule/templates/indexSuccess.php**

```
<?php use_helper('myNew'); ?>

<?php echo yourfunc($data->getSomeData()) ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do actions inside a template. For that you should separate your code in small `components`. In your cicle (foreach in this case, maybe while in yours):

```
<?php foreach($array => $param): ?>
    <?php include_component('module', 'action', array('param' => $param));
<?php endforeach ?>
```

And then, in your `components.class.php` you execute your `timetable($param);` function, displaying the result in a partial.

Comment: Equally, a partial may suffice, if there is no business logic that needs to be run.